# Transformar regras CSS em regras abreviadas usando PHP

Tags: php, css

Tendo um arquivo CSS gostaria de, usando PHP, alterar uma linha juntando as regras que podem ser abreviadas.

Por exemplo neste código:

```
margin-top: -2px; -> abreviável para MARGIN
padding-right: 40px; -> juntável para PADDING
```

as regras **margin-X**, **padding-X** são abraviáveis para a seguinte notação:

**parâmetro: (TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM, LEFT);**

no caso ficaria assim:

```
margin: -2px, 0, 0, 0;
padding: 0, 40px, 0, 0;
```

Para os demais espaços (top, right, bottom, left) não especificados o valor deve ser definido para 0.

Como faze-lo em PHP?

Comment: Não tem a tag css aí nessa pergunta?

Comment: Não deu para entender.

Comment: @rray eu arrumei a questão

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não necessariamente

Comment: O `margin-top:` seria gerado por vc ou lido de um arquivo? isso não deu para entender, qual é a origem?

Comment: primeiro teria que aprender pegar os parâmetros, depois juntar.

Comment: @rray ah, a origem seria um arquivo css normal.. pegar cada parametro dentro dos {}

Comment: O problema aqui é que pra CSS, a ordem é importante, e não pode pular parâmetro no meio. O máximo que dá pra fazer, é testar se todos estão preenchidos e são iguais e usar um só, ou se omitir algum teria que pegar o default, ou do parent, dependendo do atributo. Na verdade o problema da questão é um bocado complexo, e precisaria ser melhor definido.